# Community♦ rejected my edit but another one was accepted.

Tags: support, edits

I suggested an edit where all that I did was put code into a code tag.  I did not *actually* change the code itself.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2361833) is the edit that I made.  I thought that it seemed reasonable since all it did was improve the readablity of the question.  Indeed, it was approved by another person, however it was rejected by Community.  After Community rejected it, another person made [nearly the same edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17242684/revisions) that I did and that one was applied.  Since I am new, I figure I missed something trivial that would make the bot reject my edit.  I have seen similar questions, but none of the ones I have read explain how why a bot might reject one edit over another almost identical one.

Comment: In all likelihood, you were just unlucky and the other edit was made simultaneously with yours. When that happens, one of the edits gets rejected by Community ♦.

Comment: Community rejections are *automatic* rejections.